# Particle System with Object Instance doesnt work properly (I want my caveman with a leaf skirt to dance)

Tags: particles, rigid-body-simulation, instances

My caveman's skirt doesnt seem to work properly.
The project: caveman dances, and his skirt should move along (not stationary).
What i did:
 [image: Text] 
 - Particle System with Object (Leaf) and Vertex Group (it was all weight 1) on Skirt (on frame 109) 
  [image: Text]
 - Particle Instance on Leaf with Particl sys on Skirt (it is a complete mess) 
 Problem: 
 -Skirt goes crazy when i play the animation, and even on frame 109 the front of the skirt doesnt go down as it should. 
 What would be cool: 
 -Leaf skirt with physics (the leafs can collide), that moves along with the caveman if he moves (collision on caveman, so it doesnt go through his skin) 
 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GahQXc8QQuc&list=LL&index=19&t=700s  
According to this video, Particle sys + Particle Instance should work for this purpose 
 
 I have been trying for 2 days straight to solve the problem (Im still a beginner), and i have no idea how to do so. 
 Any Tips/Advice are welcome!!
 
 Greetings,
 Bence

Comment: pls provide blend file

Comment: https://www.file-upload.net/download-14876038/hooman.blend.html

Comment: is this what you want? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPAMt.gif. i just moved the belt a bit so you can see the animation

Comment: Yes!! How did you do it? and why doesnt it stay up on the front for you? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, here is what i did:

1. on Leafskirt i checked: use modifier stack
2. children set to None
3. i put off the particle instancing on leaf:

[image]

4. applied scale on leafskirt

result:

[image]

Comment: Super!! Thanks a lot, Chris!! I would upvote your comment, but i need 15 reps for that :D

Comment: no problem. Glad i could help! Thanks!